# Hadoop producing no output

Tags: java, api, sorting, hadoop, output

I had a hadoop job running using the old API, I moved my implementation to the new API and am having problems running it. When the job runs no exceptions are thrown but I never get any output files produced. Under the old API it would produce output files with my sorted list of results. This is the job being run:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
Job job = Job.getInstance(config, "sorting");

job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

job.setMapperClass(SortMapper.class);
job.setCombinerClass(SortReducer.class);
job.setReducerClass(SortReducer.class);

job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(inputFileLocation));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outputFileLocation));

job.setJarByClass(HadoopTest.class);

long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
job.submit();
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

long duration = endTime - startTime;
System.out.println("Duration: " + duration);
```

This is my mapper impl:

```
public static class SortMapper extends MultithreadedMapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private IntWritable intKey = new IntWritable();

    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        intKey.set(Integer.parseInt(value.toString()));
        context.write(intKey, one);
    }
}
```

This is my reducer impl:

```
public static class SortReducer extends Reducer<IntWritable, IntWritable, IntWritable, IntWritable> {
    @Override
    protected void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        Iterator<IntWritable> iterator = values.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            sum += iterator.next().get();
        }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
}
```

The logs appear as following (when running with the old API i always got the complaints about "unable to load realm mapping info..." and "Unable to load native-hadoop...":

```
2014-03-18 10:19:41.299 java[13311:1d03] Unable to load realm mapping info from SCDynamicStore
14/03/18 10:19:41 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/03/18 10:19:41 INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
14/03/18 10:19:41 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
14/03/18 10:19:41 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
14/03/18 10:19:41 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
14/03/18 10:19:41 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
14/03/18 10:19:41 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
14/03/18 10:19:42 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_local904621238_0001
14/03/18 10:19:42 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/hadoop-james.mchugh/mapred/staging/james.mchugh904621238/.staging/job_local904621238_0001/job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
14/03/18 10:19:42 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/hadoop-james.mchugh/mapred/staging/james.mchugh904621238/.staging/job_local904621238_0001/job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
14/03/18 10:19:42 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/hadoop-james.mchugh/mapred/local/localRunner/james.mchugh/job_local904621238_0001/job_local904621238_0001.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
14/03/18 10:19:42 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/hadoop-james.mchugh/mapred/local/localRunner/james.mchugh/job_local904621238_0001/job_local904621238_0001.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
14/03/18 10:19:42 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
14/03/18 10:19:42 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null
```

Comment: Are you packing your job as a JAR?

Comment: Possibly not, i'm running as a unit test through the IDE (tried running via maven install command line also). Forgive my ignorance as i'm new to hadoop - can you explain why it is important, what differs from the old API (as that did work in same fashion), etc? cheers

Comment: @James I don't know if this is your issue, but `job.setJarByClass(HadoopTest.class);` searches for a jar file to distribute out to the nodes in the cluster.  When using an IDE (say eclipse), there is no jar to send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `job.waitForCompletion(true);` instead of `job.submit();`. Since you are running a mapreduce on local, you should wait the result before the JUnit kill your local jobtracker.