# Map reduce output not generated

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to run map reduce job but not able to see the output, even here 'outp' folder is not created.Below is the console o/p.

```
**alok@alok-Aspire-5920:~/Documents$ hadoop jar  /usr/local/hadoop_test_file/votecount.jar VoteCountApplication /input/booth1.txt /outp**

14/09/06 09:30:41 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/09/06 09:30:41 INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
14/09/06 09:30:41 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
14/09/06 09:30:42 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
14/09/06 09:30:42 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/09/06 09:30:42 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
14/09/06 09:30:42 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_local336021261_0001
14/09/06 09:30:42 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/hadoop-alok/mapred/staging/alok336021261/.staging/job_local336021261_0001/job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
14/09/06 09:30:42 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/hadoop-alok/mapred/staging/alok336021261/.staging/job_local336021261_0001/job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
14/09/06 09:30:43 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/hadoop-alok/mapred/local/localRunner/alok/job_local336021261_0001/job_local336021261_0001.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
14/09/06 09:30:43 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/hadoop-alok/mapred/local/localRunner/alok/job_local336021261_0001/job_local336021261_0001.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
14/09/06 09:30:43 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: localhost:8080/
14/09/06 09:30:43 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null
14/09/06 09:30:43 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
```

Answer (score 0):

specify VoteCountApplication  along with the package, try some thing like below

```
$ hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop_test_file/votecount.jar com.test.VoteCountApplication /input/booth1.txt /outpath
```

Comment: :( still getting the same output.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-error-on-centos this may solve your issue

Comment: found  solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22476852/hadoop-producing-no-output?rq=1