# MapReduce job: weird output?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I'm writing my first MapReduce job. Something simple: just counting alphanumeric characters from a file. I've accomplished to generate my jar file and run it, but I can't find the output of the MR job, apart of the debugging output. Could you please help me?

My application class:

```
import CharacterCountMapper;
import CharacterCountReducer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class CharacterCountDriver extends Configured implements Tool {

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Create a JobConf using the processed configuration processed by ToolRunner
        Job job = Job.getInstance(getConf());

        // Process custom command-line options
        Path in = new Path("/tmp/filein");
        Path out = new Path("/tmp/fileout");

        // Specify various job-specific parameters     
        job.setJobName("Character-Count");

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job.setMapperClass(CharacterCountMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(CharacterCountReducer.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, in);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);

        job.setJarByClass(CharacterCountDriver.class);

        job.submit();
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Let ToolRunner handle generic command-line options 
        int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new CharacterCountDriver(), args);

        System.exit(res);
      }
}
```

Then my mapper class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class CharacterCountMapper extends
        Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);

    @Override
    protected void map(Object key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String strValue = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer chars = new StringTokenizer(strValue.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", ""));
        while (chars.hasMoreTokens()) {
            context.write(new Text(chars.nextToken()), one);
        }
    }
}
```

And the reducer:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class CharacterCountReducer extends
        Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    @Override
    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int charCount = 0;
        for (IntWritable val: values) {
            charCount += val.get();
        }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(charCount));
    }
}
```

It looks nice, I generate the runnable jar file from my IDE and execute it as follows:

```
$ ./hadoop jar ~/Desktop/example_MapReduce.jar no.hib.mod250.hadoop.CharacterCountDriver
14/11/27 19:36:42 INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
14/11/27 19:36:42 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
14/11/27 19:36:42 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/11/27 19:36:42 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
14/11/27 19:36:43 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_local316715466_0001
14/11/27 19:36:43 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/hadoop-roberto/mapred/staging/roberto316715466/.staging/job_local316715466_0001/job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
14/11/27 19:36:43 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/hadoop-roberto/mapred/staging/roberto316715466/.staging/job_local316715466_0001/job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
14/11/27 19:36:43 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/hadoop-roberto/mapred/local/localRunner/roberto/job_local316715466_0001/job_local316715466_0001.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
14/11/27 19:36:43 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/hadoop-roberto/mapred/local/localRunner/roberto/job_local316715466_0001/job_local316715466_0001.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
14/11/27 19:36:43 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
14/11/27 19:36:43 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null
14/11/27 19:36:43 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
14/11/27 19:36:43 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
14/11/27 19:36:43 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local316715466_0001_m_000000_0
14/11/27 19:36:43 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
14/11/27 19:36:43 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: file:/tmp/filein:0+434
14/11/27 19:36:43 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
```

Then I guess that my output file will be in /tmp/fileout. But instead, it seems empty:

```
$ tree /tmp/fileout/
/tmp/fileout/
└── _temporary
    └── 0

2 directories, 0 files
```

Is there anything which I'm missing? Can anyone help me out?

Regards :-)

Edit:

I almost found a solution [on this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22476852/hadoop-producing-no-output).

Within CharacterCountDriver, I substituted job.submit() by job.waitForCompletion(true). I'm getting a more verbose output:

```
/tmp/fileout/
├── part-r-00000
└── _SUCCESS

0 directories, 2 files
```

But I still don't know how to read those, _SUCCESS is empty and part-r-0000 is not what I was expecting:

```
Absorbantandyellowandporousishe 1
AreyoureadykidsAyeAyeCaptain    1
ICanthearyouAYEAYECAPTAIN       1
Ifnauticalnonsensebesomethingyouwish    1
Ohh     1
READY   1
SPONGEBOBSQUAREPANTS    1
SpongebobSquarepants    3
Spongebobsquarepants    4
Thendroponthedeckandfloplikeafish       1
Wholivesinapineappleunderthesea 1
```

Any advice? Is there maybe any mistake in my code? Thanks.

Comment: Try again, making sure the output directory does not exist.  If you can, post the counters report for more information.

Comment: @ChrisGerken which is the counters report? There are 4 files within /tmp/fileout: part-r-00000  .part-r-00000.crc _SUCCESS  ._SUCCESS.crc. *crc are binary files. I guess that's what you mean, how can I post them?

Comment: part-r-000000 contains your output

Comment: Do you need your output in specific file. Right?

Comment: So, did my answer help you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want your program to count the alphanumeric characters in the input file(s). However, this is NOT what your code is doing. You can change your mapper to count the alphanumeric characters in each line:

```
String strValue = value.toString();
strValue.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
context.write(new Text("alphanumeric", strValue.length());
```

This should fix your program. Basically, your mappers are outputting the alphanumeric characters in each line as the key. The reducer accumulates the counts per key. With my change, you only use one key: "alphanumeric". The key could be something else, and it would still work.

Answer (score 0):

**part-r-00000**
is the name of your reducer output file. If you have more reducers they would be numbered part-r-00001 and so on.